# Angular2 FormArray insert does not update view accordingly

Tags: javascript, angular

So I have a FormArray containing FormGroups with 3 controls.
Visually it looks like a table with 3 inputs on each row. Here is how it looks:

[image]

I want when the user presses tab or enter at the last input in the row - a new empty row to be added after it. So I added `(keydown)="addRow($event.keyCode, i)"` to the last input and created the function:

```
public addRow(keyCode, index)
{
    if (keyCode !== 9 && keyCode !== 13) {
        return;
    }

    let formItems = this.form.get('items') as FormArray;

    formItems.insert(
        index + 1,
        this.formBuilder.group({
            'start': ['', Validators.required],
            'title': ['', Validators.required],
            'category': [''],
        })
    );
}
```

Afther the FormGroup is pushed, I can see the controls correctly in the form array, however the view is updated strangely. After for example I press tab on the last input in the first row I get this result:

[image]

Last row is removed and I get two empty rows in the after the first. I couldn't find out why. Here is the FormArray after the push, the items are OK there:

[image]

Here is the view code:

```
<div formArrayName="items">
    <div *ngFor="let item of form.controls.items.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i" class="row item-index-{{ i }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start" autocomplete="off" formControlName="start">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" autocomplete="off" formControlName="title">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Category" autocomplete="off" formControlName="category" (keydown)="addRow($event.keyCode, i)">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <a class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-icon-only red">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've encountered this issue once earlier when not inserting formgroup at the end of formarray. Seems Angular is having trouble tracking the index in template for some reason, and by using `trackBy` solved it. So try:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of form.get('items').controls; let i=index; trackBy:trackByFn" 
            [formGroupName]="i" class="row item-index-{{ i }}">
```

and in TS:

```
trackByFn(index: any, item: any) {
  return index;
}
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem! tried the above one, it doesn't work for me, any other solution?

Comment: @BhargavReddy, if you can provide a stackblitz, I'd be happy to take a look!

Comment: This will work, but is a little hacky. First i recommend checking Guillermo Prandi response, as the likely culprit is - you are updating the formArray.controls rather than formArray directly!

i.e.:
 `formArray.push(...)` is correct.
`formArray.control.push(...)` is incorrect.

Comment: Worked for me for updating the FormArray using `insert`. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

In case someone has this problem but the cause is different, check if you're adding your controls correctly:

```
let arr = new FormArray([]);
arr.push(....);               // Make sure you do this
arr.controls.push(....);      // And not this!
```